# Как сделать миграцию БД при деплое на Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

Добрый вечер.
У меня есть nodejs клиент-серверное приложение, используется knex для связи с бд (postgres). Проект хранится на гитхабе, с помощью него и задеплоил его. При запуске на главную страницу заходит, а при регистации и входе - падает. Миграцию не делал, только залил с гитхаба на Heroku. На офф сайте видел bash команды для миграции, но не могу понять, куда их вводить. Подскажите, как смигрировать бд в данном случае?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо поставить Heroku Toolbelt. И потом в командной строке запустить `heroku run knex migrate:latest`

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, выдало ошибку: Error connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: а делали `heroku login`?

Comment: да, в консоли git, даже залил в ветку heroku проект повторно

Comment: вы соединяетесь через прокси-сервер? установлены ли переменные HTTP_PROXY и/или HTTPS_POXY?

Comment: Нет, proxy не трогал

Comment: повторю вопрос: вы соединяетесь через прокси-сервер? установлены ли переменные HTTP_PROXY и/или HTTPS_POXY?

Comment: Нет, не через прокси-сервер. И нет, переменные не установлены

Comment: попробуйте выполнить вот такую команду `heroku run ls` и покажите полную ошибку, если будет.